# Are there documented examples of politicians lying for the greater good?

Tags: international-relations, government

I have been watching the first two episodes of HBO’s Chernobyl show and after that my girlfriend was translating some news bulletin made by the Russians 4 days after the accident.

The video, which we found in YouTube, was quite funny by today’s standard since it was blatant lying but we were discussing about afterwards:

The options were to tell the truth, risk a mass panic and more casualties resulting from it.

Or, lie to the populating and get some casualties while keeping the peace.

Panic could potentially hamper efforts to cause the problem by disrupting access to some resources, etc.

So, in this case, it could be argued that they lied for the greater good.

Are there documented examples where we know this happened for a fact?

---

Edit:

I will narrow down the question:

By greater good, I mean helping their population and minimize harm and / or casualties. This doesn't mean avoid harm entirely, but the lie should help the outcome to be more positive.

Ideally, I'd like to find a few examples out of wartime since the context and what's acceptable are also very different in that case.

An example would be where an adult lies to a child about the monster in the well so they don't fall and drown.
I was one time where an accident happened on the highway and a motorcyclist had lost at arm and was unaware of it as he was laying down. One of the people that stopped to help was a nurse and when he said he could just feel tingling in his arm, she told him "it's badly broken, don't look". She lied to him, but she prevented him from panicking.

I am looking for this kind of examples where politicians lied to the population for a 'good' reason.

Comment: You probably should be more specific about how we're defining "the greater good" here. You might want to explicitly exclude "keeping the peace" as an excuse, since there will be countless cases of that, and they'll likely be pretty ambiguous – for example, a lie that kept the peace (good), but allowed a possibly bad thing to continue for longer.

Comment: Surely there are such politics - which lied for what they understand as "greater good". Colin Powell with his "Iraq chemical weapons probe" in the UN. He lies to the whole United Nations, to justify Iraq war.

Comment: A cynic would say "only when they speak"... I think.

Comment: The entirety of the second world war is full of examples of this. It's a bit harder to think of non-wartime examples.

Comment: I have narrowed down the question and put some examples.

Comment: To help others find examples, look for situations where lying to the public can protect the progress of a military mission (e.g. "our troops are nowhere near Bin laden's hideout right now"), where lying to the public can stabilize the economy (e.g. "don't worry, we have no reason to suspect that the market will crash tomorrow.  Please don't make a bank run"), where lying can prevent a panic (e.g. "The Manhattan Bridge isn't crumbling.  Please don't all drive over it at once in order to flee the city," or "the rumors of astronauts encountering aliens is untrue.  Don't panic") .

Comment: Just a comment as this is a side issue: your example may not be as good an example (or maybe it actually *is* a good example of the greater good achieved by lying actually not being that great). From what I heard and read: not admitting that there was a radioactive leakage implied that also no measures to counteract the exposure were taken. As a consequence of the disaster, there have been ≈ 6000 excess (over base rate) cases of thyroid cancer. This particular type of cancer is well treatable so the number of excess deaths is comparably low (but still), but: these cancers would have been ...

Comment: ... largely *preventable* by immediately issuing iodine tables to that public who for "their good" were not told that there was a nuclear accident. I don't know whether the SU did keep iodine tablet reserves or not (but seeing this was during cold war, I'd guess they did), but western countries do (and e.g. Japan issued them after Fukushima). Also, wrt to the panic: don't forget that Chernobyl happened *before* people got scared of things *like Chernobyl* happening.

Comment: @cbeleites, from the TV show, it looks like the Russians didn't have enough iodine as in one scene, in the hospital, a nurse is saying they don't have enough iodine for everyone and she's instructed to give what they have to children and she replies they don't have enough for all children.

Answer (score 6):

**"We don't negotiate with terrorists!"  --except, yes, of course we do.**

A specific example from [“We Don’t Talk to Terrorists”: On The Rhetoric and
Practice of Secret Negotiations](http://www.nyu.edu/gsas/dept/politics/faculty/dickson/dickson_secretnegotiations.pdf):

> In the summer of 1993, Israeli Prime Minister Yitzhak Rabin went on
>   Israeli television and brushed aside the prospect of negotiations
>   between himself and leaders of the Palestine Liberation Organization
>   (PLO), saying “forget about it” (Israel Ministry of Foreign Affairs
>   1993). Rabin was reasserting the long-held official position of the
>   Israeli government that, as Rabin himself had once put it, “the PLO is
>   a terrorist organization with whom there is no point in even deluding
>   ourselves into thinking we can negotiate” (Israel Ministry of Foreign
>   Affairs 1985). But meanwhile, thousands of miles to the north in a
>   century-old mansion in a forest in Norway, Israeli officials were
>   secretly meeting with PLO leaders to negotiate the terms of a peace
>   agreement that would come to be known as the Oslo Accords (Fischer
>   1993). Rabin was fully aware of these negotiations when he went on
>   television, yet he continued to condemn the prospect of negotiations
>   with the PLO even as they were being undertaken.

Several more examples, spanning several countries -- including the USA and the UK --  are provided by [a Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_negotiation_with_terrorists).

Comment: That's a lie pretty much everyone tells, and lies about.  Good call.

Comment: I don't see where's the "greater good" in that particular lie. You completely failed to explain what "greater good" is being protected by this lie. PM's re-election? There would be riots if anyone found out about negotiation?

Comment: @Miech A reputation for negotiating with terrorists gets your people kidnapped for ransom.

Comment: @Grault Then reasons like that should be included in answer (preferably by original author) as it's not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The best recent example I can think of is the infamous [September Dossier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_Dossier) (also known as the Iraq Dossier), which Tony Blair's government used as a justification for involving the UK in the 2003 [Invasion of Iraq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2003_invasion_of_Iraq).

The dossier made claims that Saddam Hussein's government not only had weapons of mass destruction, but claimed the supposed WMDs could be launched within *45 minutes* of an order to use them.

It is now widely believed to have been a blatant lie, used to manipulate the UK Parliament, as evidenced by the way in which the intelligence was 'massaged' (aka 'sexed-up') by the UK government and the fact that, following the invasion, no evidence of WMDs of any kind was found in Iraq.

In fact, an inquiry into the case for taking the UK to war in Iraq was conducted (the [Chilcot Inquiry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_Inquiry)), the results of which were published in 2016:

> The report – described by BBC News as "damning",[38] by The Guardian
>   as a "crushing verdict",[5] and by The Telegraph as "scathing"[6] –
>   was broadly critical of the actions of the British government and
>   military in making the case for the war, in tactics and in planning
>   for the aftermath of the Iraq War.[5][6][39] Richard Norton-Taylor of
>   The Guardian wrote that the report "could hardly be more damning" of
>   Tony Blair and "was an unprecedented, devastating indictment of how a
>   prime minister was allowed to make decisions by discarding all
>   pretence at cabinet government, subverting the intelligence agencies,
>   and making exaggerated claims about threats to Britain's national
>   security"

I suspect 'the greater good', from Tony Blair's perspective, was probably that he felt strongly that the removal of Saddam Hussein's regime would be a positive thing for the region (which is questionable in hindsight) and the importance of maintaining the UK's 'special relationship' with the USA, by supporting them militarily. However, this would appear to be a clear case of a deliberate lie 'for the greater good'.

Also worth noting is that the affair indirectly led to the 2003 suicide of the weapons expert [David Kelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kelly_(weapons_expert)).